# Change out of stock message on specific category in WooCommerce products

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, categories, stock

I use the following code that changes the default texts for out of stock and available product messages, and it works fine:

```
function custom_stock_messages( $text, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 ) {
        // Custom message for out of stock products
        $custom_message = 'Διαθέσιμο για αποστολή κατά κανόνα σε 2-5 εργάσιμες ημέρες';
    } else {
        // Custom message for products with stock available
        $custom_message = 'Άμεσα διαθέσιμο για αποστολή';
    }
    return $custom_message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_stock_messages', 10, 2 );
```

What can I do to display a different message for a specific category of products when the stock at this category is 0?

I have tried this:

```
function custom_out_of_stock_message( $html, $product ) {
    // Define the category slug for which you want to change the message
    $target_category = 'your-category-slug';

    // Check if the product belongs to the specified category
    if ( has_term( $target_category, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        // Customize the out of stock message here
        $html = '<p class="stock out-of-stock">Custom Out of Stock Message</p>';
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_out_of_stock_message', 10, 2 );
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want i code for woocomerce to have a custom out of stock message but on specific categories.